# Return only the items in php array that equal to my custom field month (array_filter)

Tags: php, arrays, filter, array-filter

I am returning all of the Fridays for the current month and next month in a dropdown, which works fine.

I have an additional step where I want to only show the months in that dropdown that equal to the month in this field: $productMonth = get_field('product_month');

That field returns the following value: "May".

So I need to look at all items in that array and only return them if the month they have associated to them matches $productMonth.

I have tried using array_filter but I know $var.date('F') isn't the answer, I assume I could probably do something by retrieving the last bit of the string as that would always return the month, but that's not ideal:

```
$array2 = array_filter($fridaysUnique, "matches_month");

function matches_month($var, $productMonth)
{
    return ($var.date('F') === $productMonth);
}
```

And here is the rest of my code:

```
<?php

$productMonth = get_field('product_month');
$thisMonth = date('F');
$nextMonth = date('F', strtotime("next month"));

$fridays = array();
$fridays[0] = date('l jS F', strtotime('first friday of this month'));
$fridays[1] = date('l jS F', strtotime('second friday of this month'));
$fridays[2] = date('l jS F', strtotime('third friday of this month'));
$fridays[3] = date('l jS F', strtotime('fourth friday of this month'));
$fridays[4] = date('l jS F', strtotime('fifth friday of this month'));
$fridays[5] = date('l jS F', strtotime('first friday of next month'));
$fridays[6] = date('l jS F', strtotime('second friday of next month'));
$fridays[7] = date('l jS F', strtotime('third friday of next month'));
$fridays[8] = date('l jS F', strtotime('fourth friday of next month'));
$fridays[9] = date('l jS F', strtotime('fifth friday of next month'));

$fridaysUnique = array_unique($fridays);

?>

<select>
<?php foreach ( $fridaysUnique as $friday ) : ?>
    <option value=""><?php echo $friday; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Help would be greatly appreciated and any recommendations on making the code neater are welcomed.

Thanks

Comment: You should store the timestamp values into your array, not the formatted dates. Then you can easily _format_ that timestamp however you like in your filter function, for example get only the month in written form. Getting it to _display_ in the desired format, should be handled at the point where you are actually creating the output.

Comment: @CBroe thank you so much, that will be a lot neater

Answer (score 1):

If you change your array_filter to the following the filter method will give you the values you want:

```
$array2 = array_filter($fridaysUnique, function ($val) use ($productMonth) {
    return (DateTime::createFromFormat('l jS F', $val))->format('F') === $productMonth);
});
```

What the code above does is it runs through all the values in your `$fridaysUnique` array and converts each value to a `DateTime` object that is formatted to a string for comparison with the value in `$productMonth` (note the use of `use` allowing you to use the `$productMonth` variable inside your anonymous filtering method).

However instead of converting dates twice like this I would suggest you store `DateTime` objects in your array to start with.